# Converting Double to Long Integer Value Using ArcGIS Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, fields-attributes

I need to convert double fields to long integers using the field calculator in ArcGIS. However, when I do this, I keep getting zero values rather than the actual values.

Comment: The function int() will return an integer, select python as your parser and calculate your field = int(!double_field!). Note that int() is a **truncation** of the double, not a round, so the returned integer is **always less than the double**, if you want to round so that if the value is less than .5 above the int is lower and if more than .5 above is greater use the function int(!double_field! + 0.5) which will round up or down without having to import math and use math.round(). Be sure that your field can store a long value, this precludes short and text.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What were the precise steps that you performed to get your zero values?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding new filed as long integer, then you use calculate field
for example (long_integer_field= double_field), the result will be the values of the double field rounded.

[image]

[image]

[image]